# What are some examples of visually appealing papers?

Tags: publications

What are some examples of visually appealing papers, preferably with a two-column layout?

Basically, this is for a publication that is aimed at a more general public and should be appealing and approachable but at the same time, I'd like to maintain academic approach, structure and feel to it.

So I'm looking for examples of papers where the author put some work into polishing the design, perhaps with some conservative use of color and non-standard elements.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  Can you please give some more information about what you are looking for and why?  Right now this is a "make a big list" question that is ill-suited for the StackExchange format.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you tell us why you want to know this. Usually we submit our papers to a journal, and we have no choice about how we should submit the paper and what the paper finaly looks like in printed form.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I added more details.

Comment: You may find [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends) helpful. (They've historically been more tolerant of "big list" questions over there, I don't know if they still are.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final look of your paper is typically not up to you (the author) but up to the journal (the publisher). I cannot say if this applies to all sciences but in any kind of research I have been a part of, you:

1. prepare a manuscript, in accordance with the user guidelines that typically make you prepare a word, TeX or pdf file that is plain text with enough space in between the rows, with figures and tables typically in the end,
2. upon acceptance of the manuscript, a proof is prepared by the editors (typically not the scientific editors but the graphical editors) of the journal which you (as the authors) get to read and comment on. For instance if a figure is badly placed, or the table is wrongly set etc.
3. Once the proof is reviewed by the authors, and is approved it gets printed like that.

I have never heard of a journal where the users choose how their papers look like in print. Allowing each and every author to choose layout, font, color etc goes against most publishing conventions. That being said, there are certainly things you can do as an author to improve your papers visual appearance:

#### A) Get your figures right!

1. If you are going black and white publication then make sure there are no color coded information on your figures. If I had a penny for every time I saw a B&W figure where the blues and blacks are indistinguishable...
2. Make sure your figures are at least in 200 dpi resolution (preferably 300 dpi or more)
3. If possible, make sure your figures are vector-based so that they can be scaled up/down without any loss to clarity.
4. Make your figures in reasonable sizes; too large or too small figures are difficult to place properly when the editor has a strict layout to work with. This issue becomes more prominent for compound figures. Some journals even have limits on how many panels you can have in a figure.

#### B) Get your text right!

Reading a large body of text is not trivial, especially if the text in question isn't written in the easiest of languages. I have heard the following phrase numerous times over the years: "*An academic text isn't written to be read, it's written to say as much as possible with as little space as possible.*"  In order words it's written to be published.

Since it's difficult to read articles as is, you (as the author) can make the readers' life easier or harder by your choice of words, as well as accuracy in punctuation and grammar. Here are a couple of general tips:

1. be consistent in your choice of voice; passive voice is supposed to be harder on the reader but it is more common in academic writing. Nevertheless, if you start with "we did XYZ", stick with that. Constant alternation between active and passive voice, raises the question of "*who?*", every once in a while..
2. Try to keep your paragraphs to reasonable sizes. Too long paragraphs makes the reader lose attention, single sentence, one/two line paragraphs are distracting. Try to keep your paragraphs away from those extremes as much as you can. Each paragraph should optimally be a single "move", you talk about a single bullet-point.
3. Break up your text with headings/subtitles into reasonable and meaningful chunks (4-6 paragraphs is pretty good IMHO). Make sure these headings are explanatory for what you will be describing in the coming subsection. These not only serve to separate long bits of texts from each other, but also give the reader a framework to place the newly acquired information and make it easier to see the overall point of the paper. Also it makes relocating a specific bit of information MUCH easier several years down the line.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to find examples of highly visually appealing mass-audience articles is in "magazine journals" published by academic/professional societies.  Some examples that I happen to be familiar with are:

- [IEEE Computer](http://www.computer.org/web/computingnow/computer)
- [Communications of the ACM](http://cacm.acm.org/)
- [AI Magazine](http://www.aaai.org/Magazine/issues.php)

These sorts of publications have technical articles, but they are published for a very broad audience and are professionally edited, including by graphical designers, in order to ensure that they are visually appealing as well.